# What's a good and free plotting tool?

Tags: image-processing, plot

I would like to use a plotting tool to visualize data for image processing. What is a good (free) tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) worked very well for me when I was working on some performance analysis.  Easy to create datasets and it will plot multiple items against the same "time" base (as I was using it)

Answer (score 1):

The one I like the most is [Incanter](http://incanter.org/) based on Clojure.

The most recognized would maybe be [R](http://www.r-project.org/)

Both are very good and free.

Answer (score 1):

gnuplot works well for me. it is freely downloadable at sourceforge and here is the link for gnuplot related stuff

http://www.gnuplot.info/

Answer (score 1):

I often export data to plot as csv, and then use ms excel or gnumeric, or other spreadsheet programs to read that and make a quick plot. quite handy for small (< 65535) set of data. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the type of "plotting" you want to do - I use Matlab and find its plotting excellent for image analysis, particularly using imshow and surf. As you requested a free tool you could use Octave (an open source clone of Matlab) and its image processing library to do similar.

Answer (score 1):

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) (and its front-end UDAV) is free (GPL, and partially LGPL) plotting library. It have more than 55 general types of graphics for 1d, 2d and 3d data arrays. It can export graphics to raster and vector (EPS or SVG) formats. It has Qt, FLTK, OpenGL interfaces and can be used even from console programs. It has functions for data handling and script MGL language for simplification of data plotting. Also it has several types of transparency and smoothed lightning, vector fonts and TeX-like symbol parsing, arbitrary curvilinear coordinate system and many over useful things. It can be used from code written on C++/C/Fortran/Python/Octave and many other languages. Finally it is platform independent and free (under GPL v.2.0 or later license).